# My MouseOut keeps on repeating. How do I stop it?

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to Jquery so forgive me if I am having trouble figuring out this fairly simple issue. So I was given an assigment that specifies that I should write a rollover image Jquery code using specifically MouseEnter and MouseOut functions to replace the original image src URL with a new one already written in the id attribute. It also specifices that I should keep the original src URL within a var to be used later...so I did this...

heres my HTML

```
<section>
    <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
    <ul id="image_rollovers">
        <li><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="images/h4.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="" id="images/h5.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="" id="images/h6.jpg"></li>
    </ul>        
</section>
```

heres my Jquery

```
$("#image_rollovers img").each(function() {
    var newSrc;
    var oldSrc;
    $("img").mouseenter(function(){
        oldSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        newSrc = $(this).attr("id");    
        $(this).stop().attr("src", newSrc);

    })  
    $("img").mouseout(function(){
        alert("moving out")
        alert(oldSrc);
        $(this).stop().attr("src", oldSrc);
    }); 
});
```

So I did this and the mouseenter function worked fine, but the mouseout repeats itself 3 times and by the time it's finished, the image doesn't revert back to it's original src. I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. I've tried perhaps using the stop() but it doesn't stop the repeating process. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does #image_rollovers has 3 images in it??

Comment: Create a fiddle and let us try

Comment: use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`

Comment: The solution isn't `mouseleave` vs `mouseout` @kay27 - it's that he's binding the handler to every image every time he loops over them

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that when you're iterating over the `#image_rollovers img` you're adding the `mousout` handler to each image tag every time. So for 3 images, you're adding the handler 3 times. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ggm7kzt/) with a corrected solution.

Basically you want to change your loop to this:

```
$("#image_rollovers img").each(function(i, e) {
    var elem = $(e);
    var newSrc;
    var oldSrc;
    elem.mouseenter(function(){
        oldSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        newSrc = $(this).attr("id");    
        $(this).stop().attr("src", newSrc);
    });  
    elem.mouseout(function(){
        alert("moving out")
        alert(oldSrc);
        $(this).stop().attr("src", oldSrc);
    }); 
});
```

What this does is it gets the element `elem` and assigns the `mouseEnter` and `mouseOut` handler to each image.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseleave

```
$("img").mouseleave(function(){
        alert("moving out")
        alert(oldSrc);
        $(this).attr("src", oldSrc);
    });
```

don't bind your events in a loop try the following

```
$("img").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
        oldSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        newSrc = $(this).attr("id");    
        $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
         $(this).attr("id", oldSrc);

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1h3xwyq/